# The tough journey toward/towards your aspiration

Tags: phrase-meaning

Let's say you are achieving your goal, figuring out if it's an interest or an intention, and you say:

> Identifying if it’s an interest or an intention, then treating it **as such.**

I have googled it, still the word definition from different online dictionaries do not match my example's context, they are just another robot-like definition of an english word. Furthermore, **What does this phrase mean?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"As such" means "according to the meaning of the word" or "as being what is indicated or suggested". The text you highlighted means "identifying whether your goal is an interest or an intention, then treating it as whichever one of these it is".

Identifying whether a noise which you hear at night is the wind blowing in the trees, or a burglar trying to get in your house, and treating it as such - "treating it as such" would mean either going back to sleep if it is the wind, or calling the police if it is a burglar.

[As such (Cambridge)](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/as-such)